# copy, cut and paste events not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

Why jquery `.bind()` not working in opera for `cut copy paste` events?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtInput').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

**[Update]** Opera implemented the Clipboard API in version 12.10 as far as I can tell, although it has been implemented in their Rendering Engine for quite some time (Presto/2.10.292).

This issue is not related to jQuery's `bind` function but rather to the fact that Opera didn't support cut, copy and paste events before version 12.10.

Comment: Will thy support it in the future or is there any reasons they why they not supporting that yet?

Comment: It will be supported in the future, just hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @hallvors: Glad to hear it from the horse's mouth. Implementing the `input` event for contenteditable and the `selectionchange` event would be brilliant too.

Comment: @TimDown: yes, we know about those events being missing too ;)

Comment: For everyone reading this, the future has already happened. [Opera implemented them with Presto 2.10](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/#m210-294) in April 2012

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

what about alternative?

```
  $('#txtArea').keydown( function(e){
      if(e.which==17 || e.which == 91) isCtrl=true;
      if(isCtrl) {
        switch(e.which) {
          case 67:  dostuff(); break; //ctrl c
          case 88:  dostuff(); break; //Ctrl x
          case 86:  dostuff(); break; //ctrl 
          default:  break;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

Comment: is it possible to add there a line which would disable context menu call (right button click)

Comment: `$("#element").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });`

Comment: There's no way to stop cut, copy and paste actions from the Edit menu.