# preventing copy paste using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to prevent copy paste in a textbox using jquery.
How to implement it?

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <h:inputlabel value="Actual"></h:inputlabel>
      <td>
        <h:inputtext id="Actual" styleClass="input-tex" value="#bean.customer"></h:inputtext>
      <td>
   </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Just make sure this is not meant as a 'security measure', as you can easily bypass it by disabling java script, checking the source code, screenshoting and plenty other.

Comment: in the paste event add e.preventDefault() method

Answer (score 12):

Here to go: [Disable Cut, Copy and Paste function for textbox using jQuery](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/12/disable-cut-copy-and-paste-function-for.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Actual').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Note: *Opera didn't support cut, copy and paste events before version 12.10*

Comment: I'm pleasantly surprised to find these events supported in FF+GC. Note, however, they are _not_ supported by Opera (and I don't think jQuery could change that).

Comment: Yes, it works in Opera also..you can try this in Opera..[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/uyuzo) and it works.

Comment: Since when? [dotorro.com](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuimtmq.php) claims it doesn't.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217712/1042848) Opera didn't support cut, copy and paste events before version 12.10 and I just checked it in 12.11 and it works. Btw, Thannks @JanDvorak

Answer (score 2):

It's the most and 'official' way to do it with Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ambit = $(document);

    // Disable Cut + Copy + Paste (input)
    ambit.on('copy paste cut', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //disable cut,copy,paste
        return false;
    });
});
```

However, it only works on  and as I read isn't supported on some Opera versions. Everything outside of an input is allowed to be copied.

If what you want disable completely, `paranoic mode: on`, you can use this method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ambit = $(document);

    // Disable Cut + Copy + Paste (input)
    ambit.on('copy paste cut', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //disable cut,copy,paste
        return false;
    });

    // Disable Cut + Copy + Paste and Browser Admin Tools (all document)
    ambit.keydown(function (e) {
        var forbiddenCtrlKeys = new Array('c', 'x', 'v', 'ins', 'u');
        var forbiddenShiftKeys = new Array('del', 'ins', 'f2', 'f4', 'f7');
        var forbiddenCtrlShiftKeys = new Array('k', 'i', 'm', 's', 'j');
        var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        var isCtrl, isShift;
        isCtrl = e.ctrlKey;
        isShift = e.ctrlShift;

        string = getKeyCodeString(keyCode);

        if (string == 'f12')
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        if (isCtrl && !isShift) {
            for (i = 0; i < forbiddenCtrlKeys.length; i++) {
                if (forbiddenCtrlKeys[i] == string) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isCtrl && isShift) {
            for (i = 0; i < forbiddenShiftKeys.length; i++) {
                if (forbiddenShiftKeys[i] == string) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isCtrl && isShift) {
            for (i = 0; i < forbiddenCtrlShiftKeys.length; i++) {
                if (forbiddenCtrlShiftKeys[i] == string) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    });

    var getKeyCodeString = function(keyCode)
    {
        var string;
        switch (keyCode) {
            case 45:
                string = 'ins'; break;
            case 46:
                string = 'del'; break;
            case 113:
                string = 'f2'; break;
            case 115:
                string = 'f4'; break;
            case 118:
                string = 'f7'; break;
            case 123:
                string = 'f12'; break;
            default:
                string = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
                break;
        }
        return string.toLowerCase();
    }
});
```

And what about the contextual menu?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ambit = $(document);

    // Disable Contextual Menu
    ambit.on('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

And what about mobile?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ambit = $(document);

    // Disable Tap and Hold (jQuery Mobile)
    ambit.on('taphold', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope it helps! Corrections and improvements are Welcome!

Comment: @Shikkediel ... you are right!!! .bind() has been deprecated. I'll update it with .on()

Answer (score 0):

As Jquery 1.9 onward live event is not supported, we can use "on" for same purpose.

```
  $('#Actual').on("cut copy paste", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```